# Why MUI Datagrid quick filter does not work if the filterModel is initialized?

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

MUI data-grid version - 5.17.24

I'm trying to implement quickfilter for data-grid where the data-grid is already having filterModel logic. FilterModel works perfectly but the quickfilter is not working when the table has filterModel.

Removing the filterModel, the quickfilter works as expected. But i need both the features in my application.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a controlled `filterModel`?

The quick filter is a part of the `filterModel`, if you are using a controlled `filterModel` you can make the quick filter work with one of these options:

1. Also define/control quick filter using `filterModel.quickFilterValues`.

   ```
   <DataGrid
       filterModel={{
           items: [ ...yourCurrentFilterItems ],
           quickFilterValues: ['value 1', 'value 2'],
       }}
   />
   ```
2. If you don't want to go with option 1, and you have the `filterModel` stored in state, you can reflect the filter model changes using `onFilterModelChange` handler.

   ```
   const [filterModel, setFilterModel] = React.useState({
       items: [ ...yourCurrentFilterItems ],
       quickFilterValues: ['value 1', 'value 2'],
   });
   <DataGrid
       filterModel={filterModel}
       onFilterModelChange={setFilterModel}
   />
   ```

Or if you only need to provide `filterModel` at the start, you can use `initialState.filter.filterModel` instead.

```
<DataGrid
    initialState={{
        filter: {
            filterModel: {
                items: [ ...yourCurrentFilterItems ],
                quickFilterValues: ['value 1', 'value 2'],
            },
        },
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input; in my case, option 2 worked :)